# Native screenshot is causing error in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

As you can see I have implemented native screenshot like this :

```
screenShot()async{
String capturedImage;
capturedImage = await NativeScreenshot.takeScreenshot();
}
```

I'm having issue with Built Screenshot Path: `/storage/emulated/0/CMS/native_screenshot-20220712134258.png`
`Error writing bitmap: /storage/emulated/0/CMS/native_screenshot-20220712134258.png: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted) The bitmap cannot be written, invalid path`

Comment: please share some more code. Also from the error message  says that either the path which you specified is invalid or you have not requested the permission to read or write external storage. Check your permissions. Thanks

Comment: I/NativeScreenshotPlugin(11960): Built ScreeshotPath: /storage/emulated/0/CMS/native_screenshot-20220712134258.png
I/NativeScreenshotPlugin(11960): Error writing bitmap: /storage/emulated/0/CMS/native_screenshot-20220712134258.png: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
I/NativeScreenshotPlugin(11960): The bitmap cannot be written, invalid path.

Comment: please show upload your code and the package which you are using to save screenshot.

Comment: permissions are granted and legacyecternalstorage also enabled

Comment: native_screenshot: ^0.0.5
screenShot()async{
 String capturedImage;
 capturedImage = await NativeScreenshot.takeScreenshot(); }